# How to show only the data points that have a change in Chartjs?

Tags: charts, chart.js

Show only the data points that have a change.

In order to reduce the clutter, I want to not show the circles when the prev value or next are the same. Still when you hover over them to show the label with information.

This is how I want it to look:

[image: This is how I want it to look]

The second and third circles are the same, they must be hidden and only show on hover:

[image: this is how it looks now]

Comment: So you want the data to be included in the chart, and therefore the line to show it, but for the point marker to be hidden? And then to still show on hover?

Comment: yes, I want the data to be included and the point to show on hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slightly different approach to [WhiteHat's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52517013/3775731) (ninja'd!) that iterates the series via `.forEach` to build the colour options:

---

***Edit:*** Minor tweak to `if` to account for previous and next value in deciding point visibility and added hover colour settings to show hidden point on hover.

```js
let labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'],
  series = [10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3, 3, 10],
  pointBackgroundColor = [],
  pointBorderColor = [],
  pointHoverBackgroundColor = 'white',
  pointHoverBorderColor = 'red';

series.forEach(
  (value, index) => {
    if (value == series[index - 1] && value == series[index + 1]) {
      pointBackgroundColor.push('transparent');
      pointBorderColor.push('transparent');
    } else {
      pointBackgroundColor.push('white');
      pointBorderColor.push('red');
    }
  });

myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('chart'), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'series1',
      data: series,
      pointBackgroundColor: pointBackgroundColor,
      pointBorderColor: pointBorderColor,
      pointHoverBackgroundColor: pointHoverBackgroundColor,
      pointHoverBorderColor: pointHoverBorderColor
    }]
  },
  options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false
    },
    hover: {
      intersect: false
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Interesting approach but it doesn't achieve the desired effect. When the data point is different than a data point circle should be shown. For example, `e` should have a data point circle.

Comment: Any idea how to make it work with `tooltips: {
            mode: 'index',
            intersect: false
          }`

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following options to style the points...

`pointBackgroundColor`, `pointBorderColor`, `pointBorderWidth`

but instead of providing a single value...

```
pointBackgroundColor: '#ffffff',
pointBorderColor: 'rgb(102, 187, 106)',
pointBorderWidth: 2,
```

you'll need to provide an array, with values for each point in the dataset,
then you can change the value for the points in question.

for the points you do not want to show, use color such as `'transparent'`.
this will hide the point, but still show tooltip on hover.

```
pointBackgroundColor: ['#ffffff', '#ffffff', 'transparent', 'transparent', '#ffffff', '#ffffff'],
pointBorderColor: ['rgb(102, 187, 106)', 'rgb(102, 187, 106)', 'transparent', 'transparent', 'rgb(102, 187, 106)', 'rgb(102, 187, 106)'],
pointBorderWidth: [2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2]
```

see following working snippet...

```js
  new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d'), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
      datasets: [{
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(102, 187, 106, 0.2)',
        borderColor: 'rgb(102, 187, 106)',
        borderWidth: 2,
        data: [5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 6, 6, 5, 4],
        label: 'y',
        lineTension: 0,
        pointBackgroundColor: ['#ffffff', '#ffffff', 'transparent', 'transparent', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ffffff'],
        pointBorderColor: ['rgb(102, 187, 106)', 'rgb(102, 187, 106)', 'transparent', 'transparent', 'rgb(102, 187, 106)', 'rgb(102, 187, 106)', 'rgb(102, 187, 106)', 'rgb(102, 187, 106)', 'rgb(102, 187, 106)', 'rgb(102, 187, 106)'],
        pointBorderWidth: [2, 2, 0, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
      }]
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: It didn't achieve the desired effect but it give me an idea that worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

WhiteHat solution is good but doesn't achieve the desired effect.  When you hover over a hidden data point circle it should make the circle visible.

Here is how I did it

Step 1:

In the backend using PHP, I check if the prev and next point are different, and made a point radius 0.

```
$countPoints = count($points);
for ($i=1; $i < $countPoints-1; $i++) { 
    $prevVal = $chartChange[$i-1];
    $nextVal = $chartChange[$i+1];
    if($chartChange[$i] == $prevVal && $chartChange[$i] == $nextVal){
        $points[$i] = 0;
    }
}
```

Step 2 :

Add and pass the imploded array to the options object. *Using [3,0,3,3] format*

```
pointRadius: [{/literal}{$points}{literal}]
```

**Edit:**

Using only js

```js
        
  let labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'],
  series = [10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 2, 3, 3, 3, 10],
  pointRadius = [],
  pointBackgroundColor = "rgb(230, 247, 238)",
  pointBorderColor = "rgb(47, 186, 117)";

series.forEach(
  (value, index) => {
    if (value == series[index - 1] && value == series[index + 1]) {
      pointRadius.push(0);
    } else {
      pointRadius.push(4);
    }
  });

myChart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'series1',
      fill: 'start',
      pointRadius: pointRadius,
      data: series,
      backgroundColor:pointBackgroundColor,
      borderColor:pointBorderColor,
      pointHoverRadius: 4,
      pointBackgroundColor: pointBackgroundColor,
      pointBorderColor: pointBorderColor,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    tooltips: {
            // mode: 'index',
            intersect: false
          },
            tooltips: {
            mode: 'index',
            axis: 'x',
            intersect: false
          },
          hover: {
      intersect: false
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: But this doesn't work - as [stated in the docs about `pointRadius`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html?h=pointbackgrou#dataset-properties): _"The radius of the point shape. If set to 0, the point is not rendered."_ So it won't show up at all, not even when hovered. See my updated answer - doing this in PHP is not needed. Simply updating the `if` logic in my answer to check the next value as well achieves the same result.

Comment: @timclutton on hover the point is showing... but probably it's a bug. Your last edit is the best solution.